# Is there an equation that can lead to the correct pattern for the answer to this riddle?

Tags: puzzle

Here's a riddle I came across recently:

> There’s a group of six friends who are all musicians.  One day, they
> decide to have a few performances between themselves so that they can
> hear each other one play, each one with some of them playing and the
> rest in the audience listening.  What’s the minimum number of
> performances they need so that each of them hears all of the others
> play from the audience?

I have the solution:
4 performances. They are:

1:$P123 \, L456$
2:$P561 \, L234$
3:$P345 \, L612$
4:$P624 \, L135$

We came to that answer without using math, but to me it feels like there is a simple way to find the number of performances using math. Is that the case? What would the equation be?

Comment: A binomial coefficient would give you the maximum number of performances that are possible. Specifically ${6\choose3}=20$. To reduce that, you could observe that each person has to be in the audience twice to hear everyone else, and each person has someone who must be heard twice (pigeon-hole principle). From there, I am not sure. I think there is a quick way, but I have to think about it.

Comment: Note that you don't have to have 3 playing and listening at a time. Any number can play or listen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define a $6\times6$ matrix as follows
$$
\mathscr{M}^{(p)}_{ij}=\begin{cases}
0&\text{if i=j}\\
1&\text{if i-th musician has heard j-th musician play after p-th performance}\\
2&\text{if i-th musician is yet to hear j-th musician play after p-th performance}
\end{cases}
$$ 
The goal is to make every off-diagonal entry $1$ with least $p$. $\mathscr{M}^{(0)}$ has $30$ off-diagonal entries that aren't $1$. So we have to change $30$ entries. If during one performance there are $x$ performers and $y$ listeners, the maximum number of entries that can be changed due to that performance is $xy$ in which case none of the listeners had listened to any of the performers before.
$$
x+y=6\implies x^2+y^2+2xy=36\implies4xy\le36\text{ by AM-GM}\\
\implies xy\le9
$$
So we need at least $\left\lceil{30\over9}\right\rceil=4$ performamces. The arrangement of the performances in the OP shows that $4$ indeed gets the job done. Replacing $6$ with $n$ we see the lower bound on the required number of performances achieved this way is 
$$\left\lceil{n(n-1)\over{n^2\over4}}\right\rceil=\left\lceil{4(1-{1\over n})}\right\rceil=\begin{cases}
4,& n>4\\
3,& 3\le n\le4\\
2,& n=2
\end{cases}$$
And to get as close to this lower bound as possible we need to choose $x,y$ in such a way that $xy$ is as close to ${n^2\over4}$ as possible which means for even $n$ we should choose $x=y={n\over2}$ and for odd $n$ we should have $\{x,y\}=\{{n+1\over2},{n-1\over2}\}$.

Comment: That abs(30/9) should be abs(36/9), correct?

Comment: nope that's ceilng function

Comment: oh yea. reading too fast. thanks.

Comment: I don't fully understand the matrix part. Are you able to go more in-depth with that?

Comment: The matrix part isn't important at all. I'm not using any properties of the matrix.  $0,1,2$ are completely arbitrary. I used the matrix to mathematically express the problem. That's it. If you want you can think that each of the $6$ musician needs to listen $5$ other musicians. So we need to have $6\times5=30$ different individual listens...

Comment: Ok yes that makes sense. Thanks!